# in python hdfs Is there a way to use wildcard or regex in the list method?

Tags: python, regex, wildcard, python-hdfs

In linux **hadoop fs -ls** I can use wildcard (/sandbox/*) but the pyhon hdfs client list method fails on this as an unknown path. Is there a different way to use wildcards in python-hdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/os-walk-and-fnmatch-in-python/) which uses os.walk with fnmatch, and adopted it to hadoop_client.

here is an example for finding csv files:

```
for root, dirs, files in hc.walk(Path):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.csv'):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```